# Not able to select a particular value from drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, dropdown

I've two drop downs, first one populated using DOM parser and JSTL. Depending upon the value of first drop down, the second drop down will be populated and I've done that using jQuery and ajax. I'm able to see the content/items of the second dropdown but I'm not able to select any other item except the default one.

Here is my servlet:

```
package report;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ServiceToFetchSubType
 */
public class ServiceToFetchSubType extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ServiceToFetchSubType() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String value=request.getParameter("name");
        System.out.println("The Value is: "+value);

        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        if(value.equals("Superman"))
        {
            arrayList.add("Doomsday");
            arrayList.add("Darkseid");
            arrayList.add("Lex Luthor");

            /*request.setAttribute("arry", arrayList);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome.jsp").forward(request, response);*/   
        }

        String json = new Gson().toJson(arrayList);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write(json);

    }

}
```

Here is my jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
        <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
        <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/noscript.css" /></noscript>
        <%@  taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".dropdown").click(function (event) {
                    var name = $("#doctype").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'ServiceToFetchSubType',
                        data: { name: name },
                        type: 'post',
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (response) {
                            var select = $('#docsubtype');
                            select.find('option').remove();
                            $.each(response, function (index, value) {
                                $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo(select);
                            });
                            callback.apply(select);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Wrapper -->
        <div id="wrapper">

            <!-- Header -->
            <header id="header">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <h1>Drop Down Menu</h1>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <select name="doctype" id="doctype" class="my_dropdown" style="color: white; background: #655D78">
                                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Doc Type</option>
                                <c:foreach items="${bt}" var="doctypes">
                                             <option><c:out value="${doctypes}"/></option>
                                </c:foreach>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <select name="doctype" id="docsubtype" class="my_dropdown" style="color: white; background: #655D78">
                                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Doc SubType</option>
                                <option></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <!-- Main -->
            <!-- Footer -->
            <footer id="footer">
                <p class="copyright">&copy; Design: Content Management OPS</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

        <!-- BG -->
        <div id="bg"></div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm very new to jQuery and Ajax, so any kind of help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: First select has `name="doctype" id="doctype"` the second has `name="doctype" id="docsubtype"` Two of the same name. `name` parameter should be distinct. If you wish to array the `name` value use `name="doctype[]"`

Comment: Yes, but I don't think jQuery works with 'id', so having the doesn't matter if I'm not wrong.

Comment: I assume you need to `$('<option>').append()` first rather than `$('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo(select);` after or the DOM will not update / be directly written to. example: `$('<option>').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",value).text(value))`

Comment: Correction* `$('#docsubtype').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",value).text(value))`

Comment: It's not working. I feel something is wrong with .click event. Whenever I'm trying to select a different item from the drop down, for a fraction second I could see that item as selected then automatically the default value comes in.

Comment: Your class for the selects are `my_dropdown` yet your onclick function is triggered on `dropdown`

Comment: It is not working with .change event either. :(

Comment: Plus you don't want to trigger the same function for the second dropdown, it will repeatedly update the second dropdown and you won't get your results. Change the classname of the second dropdown and deal with that separately when clicked .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145122/discussion-between-pokeybit-and-zeus07).

Comment: @pokeybit Yes, thank you so much! the class name was same for both the drop downs hence the conflict! 
I've fixed it, it's working fine now! :)